# Why is my python class being executed twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am currently trying to write an script which takes an user input and then prints it out through a class which is located in another file. But when running my script I have to give the programm the input twice which is then being printed out thrice because of an weird reason. I also searched up some other similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them helped me fixing my problem.

This is the code in the first file:

```
#this is main.py
global test_input    
test_input = input('give me an input: ')
if 'i like cookies' in test_input:   
    from test import *
    test_class.test()
```

This is the code in the second file:

```
#this is test.py
class test_class():
    def test():
        from main import test_input
        print(test_input)
```

What the output looks like after running the script:

```
give me an input: i like cookies
give me an input: i like cookies #this second input is created because the function is being executed twice. In this example I would've typed in i like cookies twice
i like cookies
i like cookies 
i like cookies
```

What the ouput should look like:

```
give me an input: i like cookies
i like cookies
```

I would be very very glad if someone could help me out with solving this problem and explaining to me what I've made wrong:)

Thank's for every suggestion and help in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is punishing you for bad programming practices.  ;)  The issue is that, when you run a program, that module is not considered to be imported.  So, when you get into `test_class.test()`, your `from main` statement actually causes your main program to be loaded AGAIN.  It will do the input call again, and will call `test_class.test()` again.  This time, `main` has already been imported, so it doesn't need to do it again, and thing go normally.

It is horrible practice for a submodule to try to import something from a main module.  If your module function needs a value, then pass it as a parameter.

Comment: ooo ok understand:) Thank you very very much time for your help and effort:) This fixed it for me:D

Comment: Almost any time you're using the `global` keyword it's an indicator that something is about to go horribly wrong.